# Remote Apps Not Showing

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

I am trying to get RD Web Access working.

- Installed the following Roles all on a server:

  - Remote Desktop Session Host
  - Remote Desktop Licensing
  - Remote Desktop Connection Broker
  - Remote Desktop Web Access

I have added a collection called ***Server004Access*** and gave access to the user group ***Domain Users***.  I have published three remote apps just to test it out.  I have also created certificates and installed them on the users computers.

Here are the screenshots showing the apps and that the user is connect to the collection:

[image]

[image]

When I try accessing the RemoteApps via the web this is what I get:

[image]

**Why am I not seeing Calculator, Paint, and WordPad as Remote Apps in the browser?  Did I miss a step?**